# From routes of points make lines postgres ST_Makeline()

Tags: postgresql, multipoint

I have a dataset full of points that are routes. The data has time and id's with which I was able to `ST_Union` all the right points to form the multipoint for each route. Now I am trying to create a line of these multipoints. This is a harder challenge then I thought. `ST_makeline` just connects all points with each other and doesnt follow any order.

Now I think I need to reshape my multipoint to an array and provide this as an array to the `ST_makeline()`. But I am not sure if this is the right method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members in a MultiPoint geometry are not supposed to be in any fixed order so forget it. Instead read the documentation from http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html and follow and modify the first example

```
-- If you are using PostgreSQL 9.0+
-- (you can use the new ORDER BY support for aggregates)
-- this is a guaranteed way to get a correctly ordered linestring
-- Your order by part can order by more than one column if needed
SELECT gps.gps_track, ST_MakeLine(gps.the_geom ORDER BY gps_time) As newgeom
    FROM gps_points As gps
    GROUP BY gps.gps_track;
```

Comment: I just had to make use of the source points and not the multipoint I already created. Thanks for the example. With that I got it pretty quickly.